# Dependency injection with Hilt of interface classes with suspend function blocks

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I declare a class that uses suspend function. This class is meant to be a singleton dependency injected by Hilt library on Android:

```
interface Foo {
   suspend fun send(v: Int)
   suspend fun receive(): Int
}
class FooImpl @Inject () {
   var channel: Channel<Int>(2, BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
   override suspend fun send(v: Int) {
       channel.send(v)
   }
   override suspend fun receive(): Int {
       channel.receive()
   }
}

//FIRST CASE:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class FooModule {
  @Binds
  abstract fun bindFoo(foo: FooImpl): Foo
 }
```

Then if when I call the receive function it get blocked forever. No data is received, example:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class Bar: Service {
  @Inject
  lateinit var foo: Foo
  private val scope = CoroutineScope(Job() + Dispatchers.Default)
  //...
  fun doSomething() {
    scope.launch() {
      foo.receive()
      //coroutine execution never reach this line
    }
  }
}
```

In this simple case, as `Foo` is a singleton I could implement a simple work around. If Foo is implemented this way within Hilt, I have no trouble:

```
//SECOND_CASE:
val FOO: Foo = FooImpl()

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object FooModule {
   @Provides
   fun providesFoo(): Foo {
      return FOO
   }
}
```

I am wondering weither it is a Hilt bug or my FIRST_CASE hilt module implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never declare `FooImpl` as a singleton, so every time it is injected, you get a fresh instance. 
In case you assumed that this is what `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` does, it is not. This annotation only tells hilt that `FooModule` itself should be a singleton and is not scoped to the lifecycle of an Activity, ViewModel or Fragment.

You need to add `@Singleton` to either `FooImpl` or the method binding it:

Option 1

```
interface Foo {
   suspend fun send(v: Int)
   suspend fun receive(): Int
}

@Singleton
class FooImpl @Inject constructor() : Foo {
   ...
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class FooModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFoo(foo: FooImpl): Foo
}
```

Option 2

```
interface Foo {
   suspend fun send(v: Int)
   suspend fun receive(): Int
}

class FooImpl @Inject constructor() : Foo {
   ...
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class FooModule {
    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindFoo(foo: FooImpl): Foo
}
```

Comment: I followed the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#inject-interfaces). Is this doc wrong?

Comment: No why would you think that? Their singleton example uses both `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` on the module and `@Singleton` on the abstract binding method. The section you linked only talks about how to inject interfaces in general.

Comment: An example on how to bind an interface and make it a singleton is given [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-scopes), right before the "Component hierarchy" section. It uses the exact same pattern as "Option 2" from my answer.

Comment: ... I got it; I thought Hilt was meant to provide a single instance for each scope. It is actualy an option.